# MVC5 Model Binding from JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm having troubles at figuring out the model from a JSON post data.

The JSON:

```
{  
"http://www.xxxx.com/":{  
    "articulo":[  
        {  
            "descripcion":{  
                "innerHTML":"Newskill Nukite Ratón Gaming MMO/MOBA RGB 16000 DPI",
                "nodeName":"SPAN",
                "treeDepth":17,
                "className":"",
                "childNodesLength":1,
                "childrenLength":0,
                "clientHeight":0,
                "parentNodeName":"A",
                "parentChildNodeslength":1
            },
            "img":{  
                "innerHTML":"",
                "nodeName":"IMG",
                "treeDepth":17,
                "className":"",
                "childNodesLength":0,
                "childrenLength":0,
                "height":210,
                "clientHeight":210,
                "parentNodeName":"A",
                "parentChildNodeslength":3
            }
        },
        {  
            "comentarios":{  
                "innerHTML":"(52)",
                "nodeName":"SPAN",
                "treeDepth":20,
                "className":"",
                "childNodesLength":1,
                "childrenLength":0,
                "clientHeight":0,
                "parentNodeName":"DIV",
                "parentChildNodeslength":15
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

My model:

```
public class GreatClass
{
    public IList url { get; set; } = new List<KeyValuePair<string, IList>>();
    private IList groups { get; set; } = new List<KeyValuePair<string, IList[]>>();
    public IList[] subGroups { get; set; }
    private IList metadata { get; set; } = new List<KeyValuePair<string, MetadataJSON>>();

    public partial class MetadataJSON
    {
        public string innerHTML { get; set; }
        public string nodeName { get; set; }
        public int treeDepth { get; set; }
        public string className { get; set; }
        public int childNodesLength { get; set; }
        public int childrenLength { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> height { get; set; }
        public int clientHeight { get; set; }
        public string parentNodeName { get; set; }
        public int parentChildNodesLength { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

- I have another doubt here: should I remove the `new List<KeyValuePair<string, IList>>();` `new List<KeyValuePair<string, IList[]>>();`, `= new List<KeyValuePair<string, MetadataJSON>>();` statements?

So, following the scheme and from down to up:

1. I have static data that they'll be always there - the MetadataJSON -.
2. I have a list with string by key where MetadataJSON is the value.
3. That list is the element of an array (articulo) that contains other lists.
4. Then I have another list with string as key and array of lists as value.
5. And at last, I have another list with string as key containing list as value.

I'm kinda lost because I think my logic implementation is OK and the mistake is probably at the generation of the JSON.

Of course, my controller's method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetJSONData(GreatClass JSONData)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Json(JSONData);
        }
        else
        {
            string errorMessage = "<div class=\"validation-summary-errors\">"
              + "The following errors occurred:<ul>";
            foreach (var key in ModelState.Keys)
            {
                var error = ModelState[key].Errors.FirstOrDefault();
                if (error != null)
                {
                    errorMessage += "<li class=\"field-validation-error\">"
                     + error.ErrorMessage + "</li>";
                }
            }
            errorMessage += "</ul>";
            return Json(errorMessage);
        }
    }
```

The response:

[Making the POST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTxZc.png)

[VS 2015 debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUSss.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are sending an object with an attribute named `"http://www.xxxx.com/"` you don't have that in your C# model (and you can't have one named like that).
You need to send an object with this structure:

```
{  
    "innerHTML":"Newskill Nukite Ratón Gaming MMO/MOBA RGB 16000 DPI",
    "nodeName":"SPAN",
    "treeDepth":17,
    "className":"",
    "childNodesLength":1,
    "childrenLength":0,
    "clientHeight":0,
    "parentNodeName":"A",
    "parentChildNodeslength":1
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't be following the structure I'd like to make.

Comment: Because you're assigning the full metadata object directly to url. What about the rest? groups and subgroups?
Sorry for the 2 comments, I pressed enter and it sent it directly.

Comment: I'd like to have a lot of urls (in this case I wrote only "xxx.com") that would contain a lot of groups (in this case I only wrote "articulo") etc.

Comment: Forget the metadata, just focus on your business layer. Write a model class that represents your business object then send a json that has the same structure

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" my problem using IDictionary and modifying the JSON (I have no other idea of how to solve it with the original JSON).

```
public class GreatClass
{
    public IDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, MetadataJSON>[]>> url { get; set; }

    public partial class MetadataJSON
    {
        public string innerHTML { get; set; }
        public string nodeName { get; set; }
        public int treeDepth { get; set; }
        public string className { get; set; }
        public int childNodesLength { get; set; }
        public int childrenLength { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> height { get; set; }
        public int clientHeight { get; set; }
        public string parentNodeName { get; set; }
        public int parentChildNodesLength { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and the JSON:

```
{
"url":
[
    { 
        Key: 'http://xxxx.com', Value: 
        [
            {
                Key: 'articulos', Value:   
                [
                    {  
                        "descripcion":{  
                            "innerHTML":"Newskill Nukite Ratón Gaming MMO/MOBA RGB 16000 DPI",
                            "nodeName":"SPAN",
                            "treeDepth":17,
                            "className":"",
                            "childNodesLength":1,
                            "childrenLength":0,
                            "clientHeight":0,
                            "parentNodeName":"A",
                            "parentChildNodeslength":1
                        },
                        "img":{  
                            "innerHTML":"",
                            "nodeName":"IMG",
                            "treeDepth":17,
                            "className":"",
                            "childNodesLength":0,
                            "childrenLength":0,
                            "height":210,
                            "clientHeight":210,
                            "parentNodeName":"A",
                            "parentChildNodeslength":3
                        }
                    },
                    {  
                        "comentarios":{  
                            "innerHTML":"(52)",
                            "nodeName":"SPAN",
                            "treeDepth":20,
                            "className":"",
                            "childNodesLength":1,
                            "childrenLength":0,
                            "clientHeight":0,
                            "parentNodeName":"DIV",
                            "parentChildNodeslength":15
                        }
                    }      
                ]
            }
        ]                                    
    }
]
```

}

Please, if you managed to solve it without editing the original JSON, it would be really appreciated.